# me sale error en case y no se porque porfavor ayuda urgente

Tags: c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{int i,n1,n2,sum,res,mul,div,n;
printf("INGRESE LA OPCION QUE DESEA ");
scanf("%d",&i);
switch(i)
case 1:
printf("/n Ingrese un numero");
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n>0)
    {printf("/n POSITIVO");}
    else
    {if(n<0)
    printf("/n NEGATIVO");}
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;}
{ case 2:
    printf("in opcion suma");
    printf("in ingrese el primer numero");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("in ingrese el segundo numero");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    sum=n1+n2;
    printf("la suma es: %d",sum);
    break;
    case 2:
        printf("in opcion de resta");
        printf("in ingrese el primer numero");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("in ingrese el segundo numero");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        res=n1-n2;
        printf("la resta es:%d",res);
        break;
        case 3:
            printf("in opcion de multiplicacion");
                    printf("in ingrese el primer numero");
                    scanf("%d",&n1);
                    printf("in ingrese el segundo numero");
                    scanf("%d",&n2);
                    mul=n1*n2;
                    printf("la multiplicacion es:%d",mul);
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        printf("in opcion division");
                                printf("in ingrese el primer numero");
                                scanf("%d",&n1);
                                printf("in ingrese el segundo numero");
                                scanf("%d",&n2);
                                div=n1/n2;
                                printf("la division es: %d",div);
                                break;
}}
{ case 3:
    {printf("OPCION DE EDAD")
     int edad;
     printf( "\n   Introduzca edad: " );
     scanf( "%d", &edad );

    if ( edad >= 0 && edad <= 120 )
        if ( edad < 2 )
            printf( "\n   BEB%c", 144 );
        else
            if ( edad < 13 )
                printf( "\n   NI%cO", 165 );
            else
                if ( edad < 18 )
                    printf( "\n   ADOLESCENTE" );
                else
                    if ( edad < 31 )
                        printf( "\n   JOVEN");
                    else
                        if ( edad < 65 )
                            printf( "\n   ADULTO" );
                        else
                            printf( "\n   ANCIANO" );
    else
        printf( "\n   ERROR: Edad incorrecta." );

    getch(); /* Pausa */

   return 0;
}}
```

Comment: ayuda porfavor me sale el error en case 2 y no se como solucionarlo este es el error que me sale 19 1 C:\Users\ninsp\Downloads\david suares y jenniffer jaramillo\Positivo y negativo.cpp [Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token     ayuda

Comment: Eso es por que tienes un punto y coma donde no debería ir o creo que es porque tienes dos '}' luego del return 0;. Revisa que la llave de cierre corresponda al del main(). Tu código así está inentendible.

Comment: El orden tiene que:
swicth
   case 1: break
   case 2:  switch 
                     case 1: break;:
                     case 2: break; 
 break;

esto para seguir una estructura.

Comment: el orden tiene que......

Comment: Luego del switch() va { TUS CASE }

Comment: entonces como deberia acomodarlo ??

Comment: La verdad te recomiendo seguir practicando y trata de que tu código sea más ordenado... Mira mi respuesta abajo para que veas cómo es la estructura de un switch case

Comment: no me aperece el mensaje podrias volver a mandarlo porfiii

Comment: nose si es mucho para pedir pero no podrian mostrarmelo como seria completo y arreglado lo unico que quiero ess que me diga si un numero es positivo o negativo que me opere suma resta multiplicaion  division y que me diga si es juven adulto o anciano porfavor no se que mas hacer

Comment: porfavor ayudenme nose que mas hacer solo necesito un programa que haga las funciones nombrabas anteriormente para no quedarme en suples ayuda

Comment: Lo único que te recomiendo es  que aprendas a darle formato a tu código, de lo contrario, no sabríamos que sólo tienes errores tipográficos en el.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en tu switch, es así:

```
switch(Variable){
case 1: código;
break
case 2: código;
break;
default: código;
break;
}
```

te falta la llave luego de los paréntesis del switch.

Answer (score 0):

en la linea 19 tiens un "{" mal colocado, debes corregir la sintáxis.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

```
switch(1) {
    case 1: {  int x = 0;
               std::cout << x << '\n';
               break;
            } // scope of 'x' ends here
    default: std::cout << "default\n"; // no error
             break; 
}
```